# Is it possible to develop with Silverlight on a Mac?

Tags: silverlight, macos

I've been searching through the Microsoft Silverlight site, and I am guessing the answer  to my question will be no.

But is there any non official or official version of the Silverlight development SDK for Mac OS?

I want to avoid installing Windows, but I want to develop in Silverlight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is yes, you surely can.  You will need to use eclipse.  It isn't as easy, but it sure is possible.

Good luck!

Link Heaven:

- [Eclipse 4 Silverlight](http://www.eclipse4sl.org/download/)
- [A video of Shawn Wildermuth showing this at the MIX09 Conference](http://wildermuth.com/2009/03/21/My_Mini-Session_at_MIX09_(Eclipse_and_Silverlight))

Comment: Darn, video requires Silverlight ... I could have anticipated this, but disappointing anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There is also MonoDevelop which is going to support it soon, but its not quite there.

Comment: Would this develop Moonlight apps only, or would they work with Silverlight too?

Comment: Mono has a ways to go on Silverlight support. Moonlight covers only the Silverlight 1.0 API, I believe. It's good enough for streaming media right now, but not much else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the answer you get does turn out to be "No"...

I use a VM (Parallels) to run Windows XP on my Mac Pro.  The performance of Visual Studio 2008 is actually fine in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Mac OS X to develop with Silverlight 3, using IronRuby and IronPython and TextMate. It is very pleasant to use!

You can grab the Silverlight 3 Beta Runtime for Mac [here](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx) and use it together with [AgDlr](http://github.com/jschementi/agdlr/tree/master). Grab the binaries of AgDlr [here](http://sdlsdk.codeplex.com/).

If you want to see samples of code that do work this way, have a look at [AgDlr demos](http://github.com/jschementi/agdlr/tree/e562c2cb73407a057e852db51b3713296aef7068/samples).

hope this helps!